# How to place a checkbox and sentence side by side using css.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing problem in placing a checkbox and a long sentence side by side using css.

This is exactly what I want to achieve.

[image]

This is what am getting.

[image]

This is the HTML & css code am using to achieve it:

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="">

<label style="color: white"> 
  <input type="checkbox" class="" style="" id="checkbox"> 
BY CLICKING ON THIS I CONSENT THAT I AM ABOVE 18 YEARS.
</label>
</div>
```

Please, what do you think is wrong with my code and how do I solve it?

Comment: Tried making the div wider? Try using `<div class="col-md-6" style="">
`

Comment: `col-md-1` is only one column wide. What did you expect?

Comment: I don't get you?

Comment: You are using the Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework for CSS (styling front end). There is a grid defined that divides a page width in 12 parts. Your box is only 1/12'th wide, which defines your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text into a `<span>` and set it to `overflow: auto;` or `hidden`

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

label input {
  float:left;
}

label span {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<label> 
  <input type="checkbox"> 
  <span>BY CLICKING ON THIS I CONSENT THAT I AM ABOVE 18 YEARS.</span>
</label>
```